# Auto Increment version number in iOS application using Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, xamarin.ios, azure-pipelines, versioning

I'm using Azure Devops yaml pipelines for the build process of my iOS application. During runtime, I want to auto-increment the CFBundle Version Number after each build in the info.plist file.

Eg: version starts from 0.0.1 -> 0.0.99 -> 0.1.0 -> 0.1.99 -> 0.2.0 ->............-> 0.99.99 -> 1.0.0

Any advise on how I can achieve this without using any third party extensions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by implementing a `script` step before building your app.
This script would use the `PlistBuddy` tool to read and increment the version numbers (assuming you're using a **macos** machine on Azure DevOps).
I'm also assuming you're using a semantic versioning system `major.minor.patch` as described [here](https://semver.org/).
This script should get to increment the version number as you described and then write it to the `Info.plist` file of your app. Note to change the path to that file if you have it differently in your project

```sh
- script: |
    buildPlist="$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Info.plist" # Enter the path to your plist file here
    maxSubversionNumber=99 # Set what will be the maximum number to increment each sub version to

    versionNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "$buildPlist")
    majorVersion=`echo $versionNumber | awk -F "." '{print ($1 == "" ? 0 : $1)}'`
    minorVersion=`echo $versionNumber | awk -F "." '{print ($2 == "" ? 0 : $2)}'`
    patchVersion=`echo $versionNumber | awk -F "." '{print ($3 == "" ? 0 : $3)}'`
    if [[ $patchVersion -ge $maxSubversionNumber ]]
    then
      patchVersion=0
      if [[ $minorVersion -ge $maxSubversionNumber ]]
      then
        minorVersion=0
        majorVersion=$(($majorVersion + 1))
      else
        minorVersion=$(($minorVersion + 1))
      fi
      else
        patchVersion=$(($patchVersion + 1))
    fi
    newVersionNumber=`echo $versionNumber | awk -F "." '{print '$majorVersion' "." '$minorVersion' ".'$patchVersion'" }'`
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $newVersionNumber" "$buildPlist"
```

Comment: Hi @Jobert, is there a way to achieve the same without using the PlistBuddy tool?

Comment: @SD4 There are some other ways. It depends on the resources that you have on your build machine. You could try to look for some XML tool to read and write the version numbers. Is there a reason you can't use the PlistBuddy?

Comment: No I'm able to use PlistBuddy. Was just wondering if there diff ways. I'll check them out thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep $(MARKETING_VERSION)
in Info.plist for CFBundleShortVersionString but
want to increase version after successful archive or build
then use following script
following script will increase like 1.0 to 2.0
but ofcourse that logic can be modified using @Jobert's solution etc

[Script to increase app version in Xcode >= 13](https://gist.github.com/m-irfan/760a3d9ede6c76b38f5e5fd748f3e315)